# How does char c = (char) -98; works?

Tags: java, primitive-types

I want to know how does following line of code works?

```
char c = (char) -98;
```

As per my knowledge all signed numbers are stored in *2's complement* form. So `-98` will be stored in *2's complement* form. So if you type cast it into char. How does this type casting is done by JVM?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `char` cannot be negative, you'll have *overflow*.

Comment: @Maroun I know char cannot be negative but I have typecasted it means its not -98 is getting stored exactly into char. I have complied and run it. Output is : "?" That means the value which is stored is 63 and ASCII value 63 represents char --> ?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3

Comment: @Jigar your font likely does not include a character for the value stored in `c`. Instead of the actual glyph, a `?` is output but this has no significance, especially it does not mean that `c` holds the value 63.

Comment: i got output as small cube sign :O :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write:

```
char c = (char) -98;
```

It's the same like writing<sup>1</sup>:

`char c = 65438;`

[Because `65438 = 2^16 - 98`]

When *explicitly* converting an `int` to `char`, the first 16 *bit* will be removed.

---

<sup>1</sup>
-98 in 2's complement is

`11111111111111111111111110011110`.

The casting to `char` keeps only 16-bits:

`1111111110011110`

This value represents 65438..

More reading:

- [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)
- [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: can u provide a tutorial regarding what u explained?

Comment: @KickButtowski The links in my edited answer should help you.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I got your point Thnksss. But I want to know what will be the output, as char c = 65438.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

They are just 16-bit unsigned integers.

People have reported that if `char > 65535`, the result was `char % 65536`, so I suppose your `char c` will be `-98 % 65536`, which would result in `65536 - 98 = 65438`.

Anyway to be 100% sure, why don't you just try it?

**UPDATE:**

I see that you want to know what the output of `System.out.println(char)` (for example) is.

> Literals of types char and String may contain any Unicode (UTF-16) characters

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

So `System.out.println((char)65438)` is then equivalent to `System.out.println('\uFF9E')`, which by doing a lookup on the UTF-16 encoding table ([source](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff9e/index.htm)) is a `HALFWIDTH KATAKANA VOICED SOUND MARK`. It will only be printed though if the font supports this character, one of such fonts is `Arial Unicode MS`.

Comment: Thankss for the help. I have one more doubt as char c will hold int value i.e 65438. So what will be the output if I print char c value. I want to know how does this int value is mapped to some character??. Thankss in advance